# How to use the EventListener Type in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, definitelytyped

React defines some (not all) DOM types in a file called `global.d.ts`, which is causing problems. There seems to be a conflict when using the `EventListener` type (coming from the TypeScript lib `dom`) in a React project, because most other types are declared by React.

Is there any way of using the `EventListener` type in a React project? I am using next.js, so possibly it is not a good idea to discard the global.d.ts file using `exclude` in the `tsconfig.json` for SSR to work?

**What is expected (pure TS):**
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-tdd-xnkov?file=/src/index.ts

```
window.onload = () => {
  // NO Problem: Listener is correct.

  // Explanation:
  // EventListener is coming from typescript (lib.dom.d.ts)
  // MouseEvent is coming from typescript (lib.dom.d.ts)
  const listener: EventListener = (ev: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log("Click!");
  };
  document.body.addEventListener("click", listener);
};
```

**Does not work in React:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dom-type-conflict-1y06r?file=/src/App.tsx

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Problem: Listener is seemingly incorrect.

  // Explanation:
  // EventListener is coming from typescript (lib.dom.d.ts)
  // MouseEvent is coming from react (global.d.ts)
  const listener: EventListener = (ev: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log("Click!");
  };
  document.body.addEventListener("click", listener);
}, []);
```

**The explanation, why React is declaring these types (from `global.d.ts`):**

> React projects that don't include the DOM library need these
> interfaces to compile. React Native applications use React, but there
> is no DOM available. The JavaScript runtime is ES6/ES2015 only. These
> definitions allow such projects to compile with only `--lib ES6`.
>
> Warning: all of these interfaces are empty. If you want type
> definitions for various properties (such as
> HTMLInputElement.prototype.value), you need to add `--lib DOM` (via
> command line or tsconfig.json).

Comment: `you need to add --lib DOM (via command line or tsconfig.json).`

Comment: @Bugbeeb I do have that (see the sandbox I posted).

Comment: Hmm, I suspect because dom is a type declaration file, the global react types are overriding the variable declaration. If you try to write `declare var MouseEvent: ...` you will get a warning because it's already defined. Kind of like writing `var x = 1` and `var x = 'a'` in two different files, the second one overrides the first

Comment: @Bugbeeb I also think that's what's happening. Both are global type declaration files, but the one of React is prioritized and incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As @Christoph Bühler pointed out it appears that addEventListener event handler receives a `MouseEventInit` instead of `MouseEvent`

So this works:

```js
 const listener: EventListener = (ev: MouseEventInit) => {
   console.log("Click!");

   const e = ev as MouseEvent;
   console.log(e.target);
 };
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dom-type-conflict-forked-1blok?file=/src/App.tsx) that I forked from yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you can see in my sandbox without React, MouseEvent is actually an Event:
`interface MouseEvent extends UIEvent` and `interface UIEvent extends Event`
Seems to me just like a missing type in React...

Comment: I see. My guess would be that lib.dom.d.ts override types from TypeScript.

Comment: `lib.dom.ts` is actually correct and coming from TypeScript itself. `global.d.ts` however is incomplete and causes these issues. I am now trying to somehow exclude that file from the `tsconfig.json`. Not having any luck so far though.

Comment: If you could adjust your answer to use the type `MouseEventInit` instead of `Event`, I will accept it.

Comment: Good catch @Christoph Bühler. Edited original answer. As a side note doing this would require a cast of `ev` to MouseEvent to make use of properties such as `target`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).

I had a similar issue in a React + TypeScript project, where the linter (`eslint-typescript`) marked several breaches of the [`no-unsafe-call`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-call/) and
[`no-unsafe-member-access`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-member-access/) rules, when using the DOM API. For example, `document.getElementById("myId")` would lead to these two errors:

> ESLint: Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.
> (@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call)

> ESLint: Unsafe member access .getElementById on an `any` value.
> (@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)

Like @Bugbeeb and @Christoph Bühler, I think that this happens because the empty type declarations from React somehow override TypeScript's internal "lib.dom.d.ts" type definitions.

**To fix this,** I used a triple-slash directive (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-lib-). Insert  `///<reference lib="dom"/>` in the **first** line of the file, like so:

```
///<reference lib="dom"/>

// Your code
document.getElementById("myId")
// ...
```

With this line, TypeScript explicitly includes the built-in lib file, and should prioritize their own type declarations over React's.

N.b.: In the project I work on, I only had to do this in a single file, which fixed the issue in other files as well.